# QLayout with minimum space required

Tags: qt5, qscrollarea, qlayout, qvboxlayout

I have a QVBoxLayout in which I add dynamically on runtime other QWidget s:

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < value; i++)
{
    QList<QWidget*> widgetList_i;
    //... widgetList_i.append(a lot of widgets)
    ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(widget_i);
}
```

There is a lot of wasted space between those added widgets:

[image: With wasted space between dynamic QWidegts]

When I run the application, I can compress the height, with the mouse.

[image: Compressed the space with dragging the border with the mouse]

Limiting each `widgetList_i` widget height using `setMaximumheigth()` is a nice approach, but then I have spaces wasted in the beginning and end:

[image: MaximumHeigth]

Adding just a `ui->vertivalLayout->addStretch(1);` causes empty space at the end. The beginning of that layout is nice:

[image]

Adding a QSpacerItem makes it worse:

[image: SpaceItem]

Isn't there a function which sets the layout's height regarding the added widgets to a minimum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Quick answer**

Before your insertion code, put this line:

```cpp
ui->verticalLayout->parentWidget()->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Policy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Policy::Maximum);
```

Also, you can find this property in Qt Designer, be sure that you are selecting the layout and not the QDockWidget.

**Explanation**

Layouts do not have sizes but Widgets. Layout are inside other widgets, so you need to change the size of the parent widget of your layout.  `setSizePolicy`  changes the size behavior of a widget. This method has 2 arguments: horizontal policy and vertical policy. You may keep horizontal as `Preferred`, that is the default and change the vertical policy to `Maximum`, that means that the preferred policy of the widget is the max size.